# changing output of ajax function depending of value of json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, django

I've been working on a ajax function in jquery to pull data from a django function and then add certain css classes to a div depending on the value of the json object the ajax function is grabbing from the django function. I tried using if statements to add css classes to the div I want to be affected, but that doesn't seem to be working and I'm not sure how else to go about it. I included the code from my ajax function, and a screenshot of my console to show the json objects look like. Any help that can be given is appreciated.

[image]

```
$(function PYLoad() {
   'use strict';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("PY_Load has Loaded successfully...");
            console.log(data);
        },
        complete: function () {
            console.log('Reloading...');
            setTimeout(PYLoad, 3000);
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you include what you've tried in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a little odd that the json object property is different between calls.  but, with that in mind... here you go

```
success: function (data) {
        if(data.green === "green"){
            $("#myDiv").addClass("myClass");    
        }
        if(data.red === "red"){
            $("#myDiv").addClass("myOtherClass")
        }
        if(data.default === "default"){
            $("#myDiv").addClass("myDefaultClass")
        }
},
```

Comment: That was intentional actually. Each json object represents a different CSS class. It's completely situational.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the structure of your JSON object outputted by the Django function I'd suggest to form the JSON in a way that lets you keep the key fixed and the value variable, in your case the key would be color and the variable would be one between green, red and default

```
{color: 'green||red||default'};
```

and then in your AJAX function just `switch(data.color)` like this:

```
switch(data.color){
 case "red": $('#yourDiv').addClass('red');break;
 case "green": $('#yourDiv').addClass('green'); break;
 default: $('#yourDiv').addClass('default'); break;
}
```

If you cannot choose how to build you JSON then you can just use some if statements

```
if(data.green === "green"){
  $('#yourDiv').addClass('green');
}
if(data.red === "red"){
  $('#yourDiv').addClass('red');
}
if(data.default === "default"){
  $('#yourDiv').addClass('default');
}
```